# $ \overline{(A-A)}\cap\overline{B}(0,r)\text{ is weakly compact, }\forall r>0 $?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and $A$ is a subset of $X$ such that 
$$
A\cap\overline{B}(0,r) \text{ is weakly compact, } \forall r>0.
$$

Can we say that : 
$$
\overline{(A-A)}\cap\overline{B}(0,r)\text{ is weakly compact, }\forall r>0
$$
with $A-A=\{a-b:a,b\in A\}$.

Comment: Why are you asking this question again? Nik Weaver gave you a counterexample in dimension $2$.

Comment: No I made a mistake in the question I want the closure of $(A-A)$

Comment: OK; I'll answer when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is negative.  In $X :=\ell_2 \oplus_\infty \ell_1$ let 
$x_n = (M_n \delta_n, 2 e_n)$ and $y_n = (M_n \delta_n,  e_n)$, where $(\delta_n)$ is the unit vector basis for $\ell_2$ and $(e_n)$ is the unit vector basis for $\ell_1$ and $M_n \uparrow \infty$ fast. Let $B$ be the convex hull of the $x_n$ and $y_n$ and let $A$ be the closure of $B$. Then $A$ fails the conclusion since $A-A$ contains the unit vector basis of $\ell_1$. It remains to check that $A$ satisfies the hypothesis if $M_n \uparrow \infty$ sufficiently quickly. Suppose that $x$ is in $B\cap\overline{B}(0,r)$. Write $x$ as a convex combination of the $x_n$ and $y_n$ and let $a_n$, respectively,  $b_n$ be the coefficient of $x_n$, respectively, $y_n$. Since $\|x\| \le r$, $a_n + b_n \le r/M_n$. Let $Q_N$ be the natural projection from $X$ onto the closed span of $\{(0,e_n) : n\ge N\}$. Thus

$$\|P_nx\| = \sum_{n=N}^\infty 2a_n+b_n \le 2r\sum_{n=N}^\infty 1/M_n,$$
 which we can assume goes to zero as $N\to \infty$. By density of $B$ in $A$, this upper estimate is valid also for all $x\in A$.  This implies that the projection of $A\cap\overline{B}(0,r)$ into $\ell_1$ is (norm) totally bounded, and thus $A\cap\overline{B}(0,r)$ is contained in $E+F$ with $E$ weakly compact and $F$ norm compact (where $E$ is the ball of radius $r$ in $\ell_2 \oplus \{0\}$), and hence $A\cap\overline{B}(0,r)$ is relatively weakly compact. Since it is clearly weakly closed, this shows that $A$ satisfies your hypothesis.

EDIT: After writing this, I realized that it was really, really silly to introduce $\ell_2$; I could just as well have used the scalar field and replace $M_n \delta_n$ with $M_n$. This gives an example in $\ell_1$, where weak compactness and norm compactness are the same. A similar argument works to give a negative answer to the OP's question in every non reflexive Banach space (one needs to know that a non reflexive space contains a normalized basic sequence that is not relatively weakly compact).

Comment: Thank you very much, sir, for the time you have given me. The reason why I asked this question, I will ask it as another question. I couldn't answer him